# how do I send a line through the server in a loop?

Tags: java

```
Socket s1=new Socket("localhost",3001);
System.out.println("Client process");
byte b[]=new byte[150];
int n=4;
BufferedReader BR=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s1.getInputStream()));
String str=new String();
while((str=BR.readLine())!=null)
{
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(str);
}
s1.close();
```

In the above code I'm trying to read a line from server and print that line on client machine.But the client couldn't read a line until the server is finished writing all lines and closed.Please help me how to read a line from server at a time.

Comment: Can you modify server code?. If yes, kindly show that code too.

Comment: ServerSocket s1=new ServerSocket(3001);
  Socket ClientSocket=s1.accept();
  RandomAccessFile Ra=new RandomAccessFile("C:/HelloWorld.java","r");
  OutputStream OS=ClientSocket.getOutputStream();
  String str=new String("hai");
  BufferedReader BR=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  while((str=Ra.readLine())!=null)
  {
   System.out.println(str);
   BR.read();
   OS.write(str.getBytes());
  }
  ClientSocket.close();

Comment: are you using `nio` by chance? the code should work using regular `io`. Are you getting some exception that you aren't catching? Your code is pretty much the same as that on [Example Depot for reading text from socket](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/ReadFromSocket.html)

Comment: no I'm not using nio anywhere.Instead of reading a line each time my client program is reading all the data written by server at a time.But I want to read a line.

Comment: YOur server side code seems like an odd mix of client and server side code, try to understand what you are doing by looking at the [KnockKnockServer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/examples/KnockKnockServer.java) example.

Comment: I got to know what is happening.That is client is going through the loop even before new line is available at server.So how to seek the reading to a new data?

Comment: @Pavi , that understanding of yours is not correct. In the present form , the client code will block at the `readLine()` part, until server writes a line, so client is *not* going through the loop even before new line is available at server. What  you need to understand is that there must a be protocol between client and server on how the communication will take place at the application level. At a minimum , this could be manual *waits* introduced before the other side is ready to react. Do you want just one single line of exchange or several exchanges ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the server flushes its output stream after each line.

Answer (score 0):

Client code :

```
Socket s1=new Socket("localhost",4444); 
    System.out.println("Client process"); 
    byte b[]=new byte[150]; 
    int n=4; 
    BufferedReader BR= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s1.getInputStream())); 
    String str=new String(); 
    while((str=BR.readLine())!=null) {     
        System.out.println();     
        System.out.println(str); 
    } 
    s1.close();
```

Simple server code :

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = null;        
    try {             
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444); 
        }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Could not listen on port: 4444.");   
        System.exit(1);      
    }          
    Socket clientSocket = null; 
    try {        
        clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
    }
    catch (IOException e) { 
        System.err.println("Accept failed.");  
        System.exit(1);   
    }           
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true); 
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(  
            new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine, outputLine; 
    // write to client
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        out.println("hello from server" + i);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Server sent " + i);
    }

    out.close();         
    in.close();         
    clientSocket.close();         
    serverSocket.close();     
    System.err.println("Server done.. closing now..");
```

PS : add these into main methods , and add the throws clause with appropriate exceptions.